# Como dar referencia a um botão de um xml de outra Activty?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

**Este é o erro:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.octupus.ramonteste/com.example.octupus.ramonteste.projetoEscolaAluno.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
private ListView lista;
public Button btnExcl;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //toolbar
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //DRAWER LAYOUT
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


    //cash da listView
    lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    btnExcl = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnExcluir);

    final List<Aluno> studentt = escolaAluno();
    final ArrayAdapter<Aluno> studentSchoool = new ArrayAdapter<Aluno>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, studentt);
    lista.setAdapter(studentSchoool);

    //metodo onclick do button
    btnExcl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editNome);
            String name = text.getText().toString();
            studentt.add(createAlunos(name));
            studentSchoool.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

**Estou tentando acessar um botão de um xml de outra Activity, ai gera o erro acima, como resolver ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numa activity você só pode instanciar os botões que estão no XML que você setou no `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`
Se tentar instanciar um botão de outro XML, é ponteiro nulo.

Comment: Ma como eu consigo resolver isso Mr_Anderson ? pq e preciso pegar os valores do campo de outra Activity e também preciso usar o botao "SALVAR" em outro xml. Me de um help ai por favor ! rsr

Comment: Vamos supor que tenha a activity A e a B. 
a activity A é o cadastro e a B é a confirmação.
Aí voce quer por exemplo que o usuario preencha a activity A e quando ele for confirmar, chama a activity B. Aí voce quer da activity B pegar os dados da activitty A? É mais ou menos isso?

Comment: Isso mesmo Mr_Andreson. Mas consegui através da Intent e do Bundle, no final chamei a Intent com o Bundle com este método <startActivityForResult(it, EXTRA_MESSAGE);>, e deu certo. Fico agradecido pela ajuda.

Comment: Eu iria sugerir +- isso. Então tá bom.